# Is there an analogous generate_series function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if there is a function in MySQL like generate_series which usually takes in a starting integer value, an ending one and an increment and returns a array of all the values including and between the start and the end. If there is no such function how would one go about declaring it in MySQL?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? You might be able to get the necessary result by using a user-defined variable that you increment on each row.

Comment: What I have in postgresql is this:
select generate_series(0, [some operation], 1) as blah. And the thing is that multiple series are generated and stalked over one another with this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function. MySQL does not support user-defined functions that return tables, so you cannot define your own.  In v8+, you can use a recursive CTE to generate numbers.

However, the simplest method is probably to define your own `numbers` table. Another alternative is to use any-old big table and do something like:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as num
from bigtable t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
limit 100;  -- however many numbers you want
```

Of course, `bigtable` has to have enough rows for the numbers you want to generate.

Comment: +10 Anyway you slice it, it's not pretty... having to depend on the contents of a separate, special "numbers" or "seq" sequence table, or to depend on another big table that has some kind of guarantee that it will contain/return a sufficient number of rows. The most straightforward is to define the extra table, with appropriate datatype, appropriately indexed, populate it, and reference the table.